# How do I do a window effect when closing the window in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, animation, window

I have this neat bloom effect I've created with the window frame so that the window blooms open when the application launches. I just messed with frame origin and size, is all. Now I want to do the inverse when someone clicks the red X button on the window. Someone mentioned to subclass a window and then catch an event, but I don't know how to do that yet in Objective C. Also, I need it to not hide the window yet until this anti-bloom (wither?) effect has completed.

QUESTION: How do I subclass the window and fire this witherWindow function before the window stops being visible when they click the red X button on the window's titlebar?

Here's the effect. Note that my window is a fixed size of 1000w x 680h (but had to make it 700h because of titlebar). That's why I used static numbers instead of getting the current window width/height and storing it in a property for later use, and why I didn't do division math on those numbers when playing with the origin values.

```
- (void)bloomWindow:(NSWindow*)window
{
    NSRect frame = [window frame];
    frame.origin.y -= 350.0f;
    frame.origin.x -= 500.0f;
    frame.size.height = 700.0f;
    frame.size.width = 1000.0f;
    [window setFrame:frame display:YES animate:YES];
}

- (void)witherWindow:(NSWindow*)window
{
    NSRect frame = [window frame];
    frame.origin.y += 350.0f;
    frame.origin.x += 500.0f;
    frame.size.height = 0.0f;
    frame.size.width = 0.0f;
    [window setFrame:frame display:YES animate:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much easier than subclassing the window.

In a default Cocoa application with the AppDelegate.m class, you'll have this event:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
  // add stuff here
}
```

Now, slightly following [this step](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11274775/105539), we replace `// add stuff here` with this:

```
NSButton *closeButton = [self.window standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton];
[closeButton setTarget:self.window.delegate];
[closeButton setAction:@selector(applicationWillClose)];
```

Then, underneath `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, add this:

```
- (void)applicationWillClose;
{
    [self witherWindow:self.window];
    [self.window close];
}
```

And ensure you have that `witherWindow` class method as posted in the question.